# Turning JSON into a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

```
{
    "ID":1,
    "KEY1":"",
    "ARRAYKEY1":[
        {
             "ARRAYKEY":""
             "OBJECTKEY":{
                 "OBJ":""
             }
        }
    ]
}
```

Above is a JSON object I have stored in the database and I want to use OPENJSON to create a tabular format. I know I can do the whole OPENJSON WITH ( ) and manually create all the columns. I wanted to know if anyone has any idea of how to recursively or programatically create the table without having to identity each key for the table. I could end up having a couple dozen fields. I'm not worried about excluding any of the items. If I wanted to pull all the records back, where could I even begin with the new 2016 SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn921897.aspx) is the official Documentation.

```
SET @json =  
N'[  
      { "id" : 2,"info": { "name": "John", "surname": "Smith" }, "age": 25 },  
      { "id" : 5,"info": { "name": "Jane", "surname": "Smith" }, "dob": "2005-11-04T12:00:00" }  
]'  

SELECT *  
FROM OPENJSON(@json)  
 WITH (id int 'strict $.id',  
       firstName nvarchar(50) '$.info.name', lastName nvarchar(50) '$.info.surname',  
       age int, dateOfBirth datetime2 '$.dob')
```

Comment: I know about the official documentation of it. But that's manually creating each and every column. I'm looking to see if anyone has any ideas of how to dynamically create it and just turn the entire JSON object into a table.